# PHP base64 how to turn into image for insertion into database

Tags: php, android, postgresql, base64

Okay so I've got an android app that an image to my php web service.

I have decoded my base64 string using `base64_decode()`. However when I execute an SQL query to insert my data into the database the script inserts this string `\x5265736f75726365206964202333`.

What I want to know is how I can modify my code to turn that string into an image and insert it into my PostGreSQL database which has `UTF8` encoding and a `bytea` data column type to store the image.

**PHP script**

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
$conn = pg_connect("database_string");

 /* GET DATA */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$s_name = pg_escape_string($name);
$description = $_POST['desc'];  
$s_desc = pg_escape_string($description);
$latitude = $_POST['lat'];
$longitude = $_POST['lng'];
$project = $_POST['project'];

$encoded_photo = $_POST['snap'];
$photo = base64_decode($encoded_photo);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $photo);
fclose($file);

 /* INSERT INTO DATABASE */
$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO records (photo, name, description, latitude, longitude, project) VALUES ('$file', '$s_name', '$s_desc', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$project')");
```

I know I'm close to my intended solution. I think I am inserting the decoded base64 string and inserting that but missing the final step to convert it to the original image taken by the android app. Apologies for my newness to android dev'ing.

Comment: `\x5265736f75726365206964202333` is `Resource id #3` as text. So I'd say you're not getting the image data its self, but some handle to it within your web app.

Comment: @CraigRinger how can I make use of this handle to find the image data itself?

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $photo);
fclose($file);

 /* INSERT INTO DATABASE */
$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO records (photo, name, description, latitude, longitude, project) VALUES ('$file', '$s_name', '$s_desc', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$project')");
```

makes no sense. You're inserting a PHP filehandle. It's being converted to a string like `Resource id #3` by PHP then converted to `bytea`. Not what you want.

It's totally unnecessary to write the data to a file in the first place, since you already have it in memory. Just use parameterised queries (you should *always* use parameterised queries) and let the DB driver take care of it via `pg_query_params`:

```
$res = pg_query_params(
       'INSERT INTO records (photo, name, description, latitude, longitude, project) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, %6, $6)',
       array( pg_escape_bytea($photo), $s_name, $s_desc, $latitude, $longitude, $project)
);
```

See [the docs on `pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php).

Regarding bytea escapes see [`pg_escape_bytea`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-bytea.php) and [`pg_unescape_bytea`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-unescape-bytea.php). Note that these functions are pretty behind the times and may not recognise `hex` escapes correctly on output; if you have issues, issue the SQL command `SET bytea_output = 'escape';` before trying to fetch values to `pg_unescape_bytea`.

What PHP should *really* be doing is using the fact that the data type of the query's first parameter is `bytea` to infer that it must insert `$photo` as raw bytes rather than text. From your comment it sounds like it is not smart enough to do this.

BTW, you really need to read [this website](http://bobby-tables.com/) to understand on reason why parameterized statements should *always* be used. See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [the PHP manual on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). In addition to being more secure, parameterised statements are easier to get right and often faster.

Comment: thanks but I got an `invalid byte sequence for encoding UTF8: 0xff` how can I resolve this?

Comment: @DanielD Yeah, of course; PHP doesn't have a separate data type for 'bytes' so `pg_query_params` won't know it has to hex escape the data. PHP's driver for PostgreSQL is pretty behind and doesn't support hex escapes, so you'll need to `SET bytea_output = escape;` then use `pg_escape_bytea`. See updated

Comment: Okay... just to check this all comes after I've implemented this code `$encoded_photo = $_POST['snap'];
$photo = base64_decode($encoded_photo);` correct?

Comment: @DanielD Yes, unless you want to just store the base64 of the photo in the database in a `text` column. Given the stupidity of PHP's database access functions this may be the best way to go if you continue to have issues with its `bytea` support.

Comment: I was thinking to do this but I'm unsure how to produce that string as an image on a web page after its been stored.

Comment: @DanielD Er ... fetch it from the database, decode it to a variable stored in memory, and send the contents as an `image/jpeg` MIME message just like an image you got any other way? Nothing to do with PostgreSQL, try looking for some basic tutorials on how to send script-generated images using PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Currently I have a variable called `$image` and it uses `pg_escape_bytea` on `$photo` but inserts into the database, a really REALLY long string. What am I doing wrong? :"/

Answer (score 0):

I'd successfully write and recall base64 image using HTML + mySql.

Talking the example in HTML5

Below is my data on database

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApQA

You need to put data:image/< image format (png in my case) >

So for the viewing in page you need to add 
`<img src=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApQA` />

I'm hoping that this can be applied to your project.

Comment: I'm not looking to view it in this particular script just to insert an image into my `bytea` column. Any idea how to achieve this?